# Can someone tell me why the answer is "After"?

Tags: mule, mulesoft

[image]

Shouldn't the answer be "Validation Error"? The "Before" Set Payload module is passing the payload to the Is Null module. So since there is a valid payload, the Is Null module should throw an error right? It should not go to the next module. And there is no On Continue Error Handler so it should throw a 500 Error. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why dont you try to implement that flow and check what you recieve as output?

Comment: Please use text instead of images. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question for more details on the reason. Specifically you should use XML for a flow, not a screenshot of text.

Comment: I did try to implement it myself and got validation error. I was trying to see if there was something i was missing that someone here understood.

Answer (score 2):

Answer is - > Validation Error

This question is little confusing, because the answer is not visible in the visual flow, but check in the XML code.

As we can see in the XML code, if the payload is null, the flow will continue on the next component. If not, the "Validator" component is going through an exception and write "Validation Error" into the error.description. and by default HTTP listener will be responding back the error.description in the response payload. Please check the below screen shot which will give more insight.

For more details on Validations please check the below link

https://docs.mulesoft.com/validation-connector/1.4/validation-examples

Comment: Thank you. That's what i thought also. I built the configuration myself and got Validation Error. I wasn't sure if it was a trick question. The http://localhost:8081? had me a bit suspicious, but there is a Set Payload right after the listener, so it should have a valid payload. This was a mock test question i found online and it says the answer is "After" which had me going crazy trying to figure out how. I appreciate your response. Thank you again.

Comment: @ammanbesaw Dont trust the online answers. Only trust what you have received as response in your studio. There are many incorrect answers for such mock questions